# Getting null token in Flutter app after sign up

Tags: flutter, dart, http

When I sign up in my app, theoretically I need to get a token but still, it gives me null. What can be a problem?

```
if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());

      if (data['token'] != null) {
        // Save the token locally
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        await prefs.setString('token', data['token']);

        // Make a GET request with the Authorization header
        final response = await http.get(
          Uri.parse(AppUrl.baseURL), // Use AppUrl.baseURL
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ${data['token']}',
          },
        );

        // Handle the response of the GET request here
      } else {
        print('Token is null');
      }

      return User.fromJson(data);
    } else {
      print('Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
      print('Response body: ${response.body}');
      throw Exception('Failed to register user');
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It prints _"Token is null"_ ?

Comment: Yes, i think that it doesnt even saves token

Comment: print out `response.body`..what you see in the log?

Comment: oh i found and issue, my backend dev fckd up a lil bit. but thank u